# Is it possible to conveniently access the count of _thread.RLock via ctypes?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, ctypes, recursive-mutex

It is possible to create a `count` property for `threading._RLock._count` by inheriting from the class and exposing the data from the underlying attribute. This is easily demonstrated by example:

```
import threading


# noinspection PyProtectedMember
class RLock(threading._RLock):
    """RLock() -> RLock instance with count property"""

    @property
    def count(self):
        """Count property showing current level of lock ownership."""
        return self._count
```

1. Is it possible to do the same with the `_thread.RLock` by getting the count via `ctypes`?
2. If it is possible, would the code have any advantages over the version shown above?
3. If it would be advantageous, what code would one have to write to access the count?

Comment: Why would you involve ctypes or subclasses at all? If you're going to access the implementation details of `threading._RLock`, why not just access the object's `_count` attribute directly as `whatever_rlock._count`?

Comment: Are you under the impression that the underscore actually does something? It's just an underscore. There's no `private` or `protected` access in Python. You don't need to go through some `klass.getDeclaredField('_count').getInt(lock)` reflection API to bypass access control like in Java, because there just isn't any access control. It's still a bad idea to poke other libraries' implementation details, though.

Comment: @user2357112 `_thread.RLock` is implemented in C and does not expose its `count` attribute and would probably need to be accessed via `ctypes` if at all. A subclass could provide an orderly API for getting the data. `threading._RLock._count` is accessible in Python since it is implemented in Python, but the implementation in C does not easily allow such an option.

Comment: Ah, different class. The fact that you call it `_thread.RLock._count`, as if there actually is a `_count` attribute, is confusing.

Comment: @user2357112 Hopefully, the adjusted title helps to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same with the _thread.RLock by getting the count via ctypes?

Yes, it is possible, as [`rlockobject` strunct definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Modules/_threadmodule.c#L268-L274) is given:

```
import ctypes, _thread

class RLock(_thread.RLock):

    offsetof_rlock_count = 32 # on 64-bit system

    @property
    def count(self):
        rlock_count_b = ctypes.string_at(id(self)+self.offsetof_rlock_count, 8)
        return int.from_bytes(rlock_count_b, 'little', signed=False)

rlock = RLock()
with rlock:
    with rlock:
        print(rlock.count)
```

yields:

```
2
```

or a more formal version:

```
class S_rlockobject(ctypes.Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('ob_refcnt', ctypes.c_ssize_t),
        ('ob_type', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('rlock_lock', ctypes.c_void_p),
        ('rlock_owner', ctypes.c_long),
        ('rlock_count', ctypes.c_ulong),
        ('in_weakreflist', ctypes.c_void_p),
    ]

class RLock(_thread.RLock):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._s = S_rlockobject.from_address(id(self))

    @property
    def count(self):
        return self._s.rlock_count
```

> If it is possible, would the code have any advantages over the version shown above?
>   If it would be advantageous, what code would one have to write to access the count?

Both methods utilize non-public API, it is hard to tell which is better,  but I feel the inheriting pure python `RLock` implementation is simpler. The performance difference is neglectable here.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer! I like your formal version better since it looks like it would be better for a production environment.

Comment: @noctis-skytower first version is to exhibit the internal detail, thanks for your feedback.